how to display algorithm outputs from vs-code terminal into the pages of my webapp?
I have a python program in my Django app called grouping.py, I want to display the outputs of the program into my  pages of my webapp.The program works as I want in the vs-code terminals but when I run the command python manage.py runserver in my CMD it displays the error
  File "C:\Users\aqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\aqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 982, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aqa\Desktop\academic\abs_env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aqa\Desktop\academic\abs_env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 133, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\aqa\Desktop\academic\abs_env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 486, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqa\Desktop\academic\abs_env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqa\Desktop\academic\abs_env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqa\Desktop\academic\abs_env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqa\Desktop\academic\abs_env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 519, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqa\Desktop\academic\abs_env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqa\Desktop\academic\abs_env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 738, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqa\Desktop\academic\abs_env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqa\Desktop\academic\abs_env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 731, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\aqa\Desktop\academic\balancing_systems\urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('',include('academic_balancing.urls')),
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqa\Desktop\academic\abs_env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 39, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\aqa\Desktop\academic\academic_balancing\urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    path('',views.algorithm_output,name='algorithm_output')]
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'views' has no attribute 'algorithm_output'




I tried the following :
urls.py 

from django.urls import path
import views

urlpatterns = [
    #algorithm template
    path('',views.algorithm_output ,name='algorithm_output'),
]

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from grouping import form_groups
# Create your views here

def algorithm_output(request):
    #call algorithm frunction
    output =  form_groups
    #pass output to the template
    return render(request,'academic_balancing/academic.html',{'output':output})

academic.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>{{output}}</p>
  </body>  
</html>


i need help to display the algorithm output to my django webapp pages

Have you gone through the tutorials? Django has great getting started pages to help you. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial01/

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

when you run import view then first it may search file views.py in folder where you started program, or it may load some global module views - but your views.py is in subfolder - and it may find wrong file views.py

The django docs mention an import using from . import views.
The Python docs say:
import foo                 # foo imported and bound locally
import foo.bar.baz         # foo, foo.bar, and foo.bar.baz imported, foo bound locally
import foo.bar.baz as fbb  # foo, foo.bar, and foo.bar.baz imported, foo.bar.baz bound as fbb
from foo.bar import baz    # foo, foo.bar, and foo.bar.baz imported, foo.bar.baz bound as baz
from foo import attr       # foo imported and foo.attr bound as attr

Django wants you to import your local views.py file into your urls.py as a views variable. Try to use from . import views instead of import views

the import views has no impact since it gave the result that I wanted, the problem is how to display the outputs I get from my vs-code terminal to my webapp pages so if you know any way so as to avoid the attribute error I get, but avoid import error for no known relative package
